# XPath for custom Sonar coding rules

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to set up a custom coding rule for XML in SonarQube using XPath 1.0 to look at my `pom.xml`files.

Below is an example of what I am trying to query.

```
<properties>
    <hcp-lang.version>2.0.37</hcp-lang.version>
</properties
```

I need a rule that will look for the presence of `hcp-lang.version` where the version is not less than`2.0.38` so I require a XPath expression that will evaluate that. The problem that I seem to have, is dealing with those pesky decimals

Below I have an example of what I have tried (and failed).

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), "hcp-lang.version") and not(substring-before(text(),'.')=2 and substring-before(substring-after(text(),'.'),'.')=0 and substring-after(substring-after(text(),'.'),'.')<38)]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
//*[local-name()="hcp-lang.version" and substring-before(., ".") > 2 
or (substring-before(., ".") = 2 
and (substring-before(substring-after(., "."), ".") > 0 
or substring-after(substring-after(., "."), ".") >= 38))]
```

Here we're looking for version with first number that is greater than `2`...or if it is equal to `2`, then second number should be greater than `0` or third number not less than `38`...

Comment: Yeap... This might take a while :) Not the final version yet

Comment: @TheLimeTrees, updated. Final version seem really messy :) I guess you should use it as very last resort :)

Comment: @TheLimeTrees, but... if you're checking a range of versions like `2.0.0 ~ 2.0.55`, then you can use simple `//*[local-name()="hcp-lang.version" and substring-after(., "2.0.") > 37]`